# Generalized Classical Adjoints and Factorizations of the Characteristic Polynomial

Tags: matrices, linear-algebra, at.algebraic-topology

This is idle noodling, and I'm prepared to learn that it's foolish as well as idle.  But....

Let $M$ be an $n\times n$ matrix over, oh, let's say an algebraically closed field for now.  There have been a few occasions, decades apart, on which I'd have found it very convenient to write the characteristic polynomial of $M$ as
$$(X-M)(X-\sigma(M))(X-\sigma^2(M))\ldots(X-\sigma^{n-1}(M))$$
where $\sigma$ is some map of order $n$ from the set of $n$-by-$n$ matrices to itself.

Note that if $n=2$, we can take $\sigma$ to be the classical adjoint of $M$.  My main question is:

**Question 1:**  For larger $n$, what is the largest set of $n$-by-$n$ matrices on which a reasonably well-behaved $\sigma$ can be defined?

For example, let $B$ be the set of all $n$-by-$n$ matrices with $n$ distinct eigenvalues. Here's an attempt to define $\sigma:B\rightarrow B$.

Let $E$ be the set of all $(M,V_1,V_2,\ldots,V_n)$ such that $M\in B$ and the $V_i$ are the distinct eigenspaces of $M$.  Then we can define a map $\tau:E\rightarrow E$ as follows:

Given $(M,V_1,\ldots,V_n)\in B$, let $e_i$ be the eigenvalue $M$ associates to $V_i$.  Then set $\tau(M,V_1,\ldots,V_n)=(M',V_1,\ldots,V_n)$ where $M'$ is the matrix having eigenspaces $V_1,V_2,\ldots,V_n$ with associated eigenvalues $e_2,e_3,\ldots,e_n,e_1$.

Then (with $\pi$ the obvious projection) it suffices to find a map $\sigma$ that completes the commutative diagram:

[image] [(source)](http://www.landsburg.com/web/comdi.gif)

For this, it would suffice to find a section for the map $\pi$, but that looks hopeless even in the case $n=2$, where a map $\sigma$ nevertheless exists.  Might $\sigma$ exist for, say, $n=3$?  (Note that for $n$ larger than 2, symmetry conditions dictate that $\sigma$ can't be unique.)  Or is there perhaps some topological obstruction to this?  This leads me to the subsidiary question:

**Question 2:**  What is the cohomology of the space $E$?

In case $\sigma$ can be constructed, there are some fairly obvious things to say about extending it to subsets of the $n$-by-$n$ matrices that are strictly larger than $B$, but I'll leave the question here for now.

Comment: This is (vaguely but still) related to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/27675 , where I speak of determinants rather than char. polys. and require the maps to be linear. I have got the feeling that at least my question has a negative answer, but I completely lack the tools (topological obstructions, maybe also PI algebras, algebraic geometry) to prove it.

Comment: I wish to correct your statement about the case $n=2$. The classical adjoint ($=$ transpose ?) does not work. But $\sigma(M)=({\rm Tr}\,M)I_2-M$ does.

Comment: @DenisSerre: Some people call this the classical adjoint: [en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix)

Comment: @PhilippLampe: Well, I didn't know this terminology. I won't forget it.